# Ruby class and def

Tags: python, ruby

I started learning Ruby today, coming from Python.

I have a few Python examples I'm trying to use in Ruby:

```
def id():
    return random.randrange(10**15,10**16)

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = id()
```

In Ruby I've been trying to do this in a really weird way I think:

```
def id()
    puts rand(10**15)+rand(10**16)
end
class test
      def initialize(name=nil,password=nil)
          @id =id()
      end
end
```

I feel I am doing it completly wrong, so advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding two random numbers instead of generating a random number from a range? And why are you printing the number to the screen instead of returning it?

Comment: Also, capitalization counts in Ruby just as much as in Python. If you define a function named `Id`, you have to call it as `Id`, not `id`. (You may be confused because, like Python, Ruby have a built-in `id` function that returns a unique ID number for an object, so it seems to work…)

Comment: Don't name methods, like `Id`, with a leading capital letter. Methods use snake_case by convention. Also, Ruby is indented using 2-space tabstops, not using tabs.

Comment: Thanks guys, and sorry about that typo editing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts` is equivalent to Python's `print`, not `return`. Ruby uses `return` too. Also, you need consistant naming If you want to call `id`, you need to define `id`, not `Id`. So this would be the correct code:

```
def id()
    return rand(10**15)+rand(10**16)
end
class test
      def initialize(name=nil,password=nil)
          @id = id()
      end
end
```

Comment: Except that in Ruby `return` is implicit and idiomatically you’d just omit it here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Including it for clarity.